# peak memory usage from tf.profiler much more than nvidia-smi?

Tags: tensorflow

I use `tf.profiler` to record the GPU memory usages, but got confused result. When`batch=1`, `nvidia-smi` show 1.2GB GPU ram used, `tf.profiler` returned '644.06MB' peak memory. When`batch=32`, `nvidia-smi` show 4.8GB GPU ram used, `tf.profiler` returned '13792.77MB' peak memory.

anyone could explain it?